# powershell recreate structure and copy files by owner

Tags: powershell, loops

I have a sharedrive with many files and some file structure. Files were created by many owners.

I would like to create folder per file owner and to recreate file structure but with files only for required owner (copy files, i.e. blank file owner should be in "blank" folder). Can you please help?

Comment: What kind of file system? NTFS doesn't have a concept of a "blank" owner AFAIK

Comment: yes, ntfs. There are files with blank owner. I have list of those files so can change it to "abc" or smt, before running main script. But now sure how to create that main script..

Comment: What tool/GUI are you using to enumerate the owners? Perhaps you just don't have permission to read the ACL?

Comment: powershell, using get-childitem getaccesscontrol().owner commands to extract all owners from sharedrive

Comment: Are you calling `GetAccessControl().Owner` inside a calculated property? That would explain the blanks, property value would be `$null` on error (because of permission denied for example)

Comment: yes, inside calc

Comment: This question already needed a lot of comments asking for clarity. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70509840/edit) your question and put all extra info in there. Also provide a usable example and a desired result so it will be clear what you mean with _"only for required owner"_, _"blank file owner"_, _"blank" folder_.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this as follow

```
# assuming that your sharedrive is $dir

$dir = "\\SRV\FILES\"

# assuming that your folders root path is $DestinationRootDir
$DestinationRootDir = '\\SRV\Test\'


$FilesWithOwner = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse -File | Select-Object Fullname,@{n='Owner';e={(Get-Acl $_.fullname).Owner}}
foreach ($File in $FilesWithOwner){

[string]$Owner = $File.Owner
if ($Owner){
    ($FlatOwner = $Owner.Substring($owner.IndexOf('\')+1))
    $destination = $DestinationRootDir+$FlatOwner
}
else {
    $destination = $DestinationRootDir+"blank"
}
Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $destination

}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, lookslike there is error in script, probably in destination path, because I get only 1 file in $DestinationRootDir (last one copied from "\\SRV\FILES\"), no folders at all.

Comment: do you want also to copy folders according to owner, as i understand you need to copy files only according to owner, so i restricted the output of get-childitem to files only.

Comment: also please note that the $DestinationRootDir variable should end with '\' because i add the owner at the end of it to get the $destination

Comment: yes, want to copy the whole folder structure and files in that structure but only for appropriate owner ('\\SRV\Test\owner1\folder1.....\file1.... ; '\\SRV\Test\owner1\folder2.....\file2.... ; '\\SRV\Test\owner2\folder1.....\file3.... ; '\\SRV\Test\owner2\folder2.....\file333.... ; )

Comment: the problem here that if you configured the script to get the owner of folders then move the folders based on owner, so the files exist in folders will be moved also even they owned by another owner; and this is why i configured the script to list files by owner and move them to owner folder.

Comment: sorry for missinformation then, I meant to find owner of every file and then to group every file in special folder with owner name keeping the same structure but filtering only files for that owner